# Incompatible types: Required: T Found: Object - IntelliJ

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea

There is this method (abbreviated) in the project I'm working on:

```
   public <T> T query(
        final Extractor<T> extractor, final List result) {
                //...
               return extractor.extract(result) 
                //...
    }
```

with the Extractor defined as:

```
public interface Extractor<T> {
    T extract(List<Map<String, Object>> result);
}
```

In Eclipse there isn't any error but IntelliJ refuses to compile the class with `Incompatible types: Required: T Found: Object`, the only way to is if I cast the return value to T or return Object instead and I can't figure out why it is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add [type argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) to the parameter:

```
query(final Extractor<T> extractor, final List<Map<String, Object>> result){
```

The error message because of type mismatch([Raw Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)). Here is what docs say about raw type:

> Raw types show up in legacy code because lots of API classes (such as
>   the Collections classes) were not generic prior to JDK 5.0. When using
>   raw types, you essentially get pre-generics behavior — a Box(in your case List) gives you
>   Objects. For backward compatibility, assigning a parameterized type to
>   its raw type is allowed

Comment: Thanks, I thought it had something to do with that, it works properly now. I am using a different JDK for Eclipse (running in VM) so probably works there because compiler is different (less strict).

Answer (score 3):

I'm getting the same error in Eclipse.

It is probably caused by using the raw `List` type.

Changing the signature of the `query` method to:

```
public <T> T query(final Extractor<T> extractor, final List<Map<String, Object>> result)
```

fixes it.